# JAX-WS Service giving FileNotFoundException while using default constructor?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, classloader, ear

I am trying write JAX-WS client in my enterprise application.My client code is as follows

```
...
public class WSClient{
...
MyHelloService service = new MyHelloService();
service.sayHello("Test");
```

But I am getting following exception

```
Caused By: java.io.FileNotFoundException: zip:C:/appsrv/domains/xdv_v00_7772_localhost/tmp/_WL_user/geftj9/war/WEB-INF/lib/wsClient.jar!/com/test/MyHelloService.wsdl
```

Structure of my EAR is as below

```
MyEAR.ear
      APP-INF/wsdl.jar[contains MyHelloService.wsdl]
      APP-INF/stubs.jar[contains stubs of JAX-WS]
      somewar.war
            WEB-INF/lib/wsdl.jar[contains WSDL]
            WEB-INF/lib/stubs.jar[contains stubs of JAX-WS]
            WEB-INF/lib/wsClient.jar[This jar has WS Client code using stubs]
```

I found that the service class generated by JAX-WS has following code

```
package com.test;
public class MyHelloService extends Service{            
    ..
    MyHelloService(){
        ..
        baseUrl = com.test.MyHelloService.class.getResource(".");
        url = new URL(baseUrl, "MyHelloService.wsdl");
        ..
    }
}
```

I also tried to change my client as follows.But its giving me same exception.

```
URL baseUrl = com.test.WSClient.class.getClassLoader().getResource(".");
url = new URL(baseUrl, "MyHelloService.wsdl");
MyHelloService service = new MyHelloService();
service.sayHello("Test");
```

I am wondering how do I load the WSDL from  WEB-INF/lib/wsdl.jar.
Any help would be much appreciated in this.

Comment: What are you using for generated the client? Why two `stubs.jar` files?

Comment: These jars are bundled by our custom build script which I dont have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `MyHelloService.wsdl` lives in `wsdl.jar`, try the next:

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL wsdlLocation = classloader.getResource("MyHelloService.wsdl");
QName serviceName= new QName("http://test.com/", "MyHelloService");

MyHelloService service = new MyHelloService(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
service.sayHello("Test");
```

- [*Consuming a Web Service with Java 6 and JAX-WS*](http://shrubbery.mynetgear.net/c/display/W/Consuming+a+Web+Service+with+Java+6+and+JAX-WS)
- [*Loading Java Properties Files*](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/loading-java-properties-files/)